# Set DataGridView column ValueType

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to set DataGridView column ValueType? I need for some columns to set that they are double, because, value who I put into cells of that column are double.

Example:

```
 dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = artikal.cena_bez_PDV;
```

artikal.cena_bez_PDV is double.

Comment: comboBoxColumn.ValueType = typeof(double); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, in order not to confuse, let's make that `dataGridView1.Columns[4].ValueType = typeof(double);`

Comment: Taw, I got it earlier, but thank :) Add as comment to set as correct answer.